# Visual Studio switch statement formatting

Tags: visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2005. It always wants to format switch statements like this:

```
switch (thing)
{
case A:
  stuff;
  break;

case B:
  things;
  break;
}
```

Is there a way to have it indent the cases like this?:

```
switch (thing)
{
  case A:
    stuff;
    break;

  case B:
    things;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Go here:

> `Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Formatting > Indentation > Indent case labels`

Comment: FYI, this option is also available for "Formatting > C/C++", but only in VS 2013 and later.

Comment: This option also exists for C/C++ in Visual Studio 2010. +1

Comment: Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style > Formatting > Indentation > Indent case labels  
(Visual Studio 2017)

Answer (score 5):

An updated method of doing this, it's not too different.

Tools > Options > Text Editor > (Language) > Code Style > Formatting > Indentation > Indent case labels

Answer (score 0):

Tools | Options | Text Editor | c# -> check 'Ident block contents' checkbox.